# JPA: Error in join with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I get an error here:

```
@Query("SELECT p.id,"
+ " p.data,"
+ " p.protocolo,"
+ " p.status,"
+ " d.nome,"
+ " u.nome"
+ " FROM Protocolo p"
+ " INNER JOIN Documento d ON "
+ " p.documento_id = d.id "
+ " INNER JOIN Usuario u ON "
+ " p.academico_id = u.id)")
public List<Protocolo> findByProtocolosJoin();
```

Here is a link to a log file:
[Log file](http://pastebin.com/Bmq8uEja)

Comment: show the table structure for `documento` or the table containing field `nome` and are you sure it's an error with the SQL? in your link I see Invalid path: 'd.nome'  like the jpa is trying to access the path for the document but can't. also... write the result of your @query out and paste it instead of the source code.  easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

`JPQL` allows you to `JOIN` across **relations**. You seem to be trying to `JOIN` to a different root. That is not part of standard `JPQL`, although some JPA providers (e.g `DataNucleus`) may allow it - the message says that yours (`Hibernate`) doesn't for the version you're using. Any `JPQL` tutorial would show you [how to join across relations](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#FROM_Clause), and since you don't bother posting entities (that such joining would be based on) that is all that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of an inner join using the JOIN operator is [INNER] JOIN  [AS] .

Consider the following query:
SELECT p
FROM Employee e JOIN e.phones p

This query uses the JOIN operator to join the Employee entity to the Phone entity across the phones relationship.
The join condition in this query is defined by the object-relational mapping of the phones relationship.

The SQL equivalent for the JPQL request is :

SELECT p.id, p.phone_num, p.type, p.emp_id
FROM emp e, phone p
WHERE e.id = p.emp_id

Try this request :

SELECT p.id, p.data, p.protocolo, p.status, d.nome, u.nome
FROM Protocolo p JOIN p.Documento d JOIN p.Documento.Usuario u

Keep us informed by the result and good luck

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?